# Formato md-datepicker en AngularJS (Angular 1) inconsistente

Tags: angularjs, validación, formato

Tengo un `md-datepicker` definido con Angular 1.X:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="query.filter.mindate"></md-datepicker>
```

Como puedo definir el formato de la fecha de este componente?

Ya he leído algunas respuestas al respecto (como [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32566416/1468942)) donde proponen utilizar el `mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate` y `parseDate` y no me funciona.

He intentado poner también de la siguiente manera:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="query.filter.mindate">{{date : 'D/M/YYYY'}}</md-datepicker>
```

Y esta:

```
<md-datepicker ng-model="query.filter.mindate">{{myFecha date : 'D/M/YYYY'}}</md-datepicker>
```

Pero esto tampoco funciona, la validación se produce como si esperara `M/D/YYYY` y no veo como modificarlo.

Existe alguna manera de poner algun tag en el mismo HTML para que haga la validación con el formato que quiera?

Comment: Puedes revisar esto http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33475874/md-datepicker-input-format,  incluso hay un [demo](http://ejemplo.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gracias al [comentario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/48581/formato-md-datepicker-en-angular-inconsistente#comment85207_48581) de x4mp73r que iba a esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33475874/1468942) del SO original que me ha solucionado el problema.

Lo que he tenido que hacer es poner esto en mi config:

```
$mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function (date) {
    return date ? moment(date).format('D/M/YYYY') : '';
};

$mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function (dateString) {
    var m = moment(dateString, 'D/M/YYYY', true);
    return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
};
```

Y la validación ya funciona como debe y deja hacer las peticiones post sin problemas.